# R function for transposing data into new columns

Tags: r, transpose

I have an issue that I have been trying to solve... it has been driving me insane. Essentially, my data produces duplicate rows for each additional "note" rather than ordering the notes in new columns. Essentially, I need this:

| ID | Company | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | srental | skiing rentals |
| 1 | srental | last used 3/12/14 |
| 2 | hertz | car rental |
| 3 | nike | shoe orders |
| 3 | nike | last used 2/14/19 |
| 3 | nike | [www.nike.com](http://www.nike.com) |

To turn into this:

| ID | Company | Note 1 | Note 2 | Note 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | srental | skiing rentals | last used 3/12/14 | NA |
| 2 | hertz | car rental | NA | NA |
| 3 | nike | shoe orders | last used 2/14/19 | [www.nike.com](http://www.nike.com) |

I have tried and failed a few times now. Here is my closest attempt:

## Pivot the data from long to wide format

```
data2 <- pivot_wider(data, names_from = Note, values_from = Note, names_prefix = "Note_")
```

## Rename the columns to remove the "Note_" prefix

```
colnames(data2) <- gsub("Note_", "", seq(col(data2)))
names(data2)[names(data2) == "1"] <- "ID"
names(data2)[names(data2) == "2"] <- "Company"
```

## Print the final result

```
data2
```

[FINAL RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b60lB.png)

I would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: first, create an id_note for each (id, company), i.e data <- group_by(data, id, company) |> mutate(id_note = 1:n()) 
Then pivot_wider using id_note as names_from

Answer (score 4):

Use `row_number()` by group, and then pivot wider:

```
pivot_wider(
  data %>% group_by(Company) %>% mutate(i=row_number()),
  names_from=i,
  values_from=Note,
  names_prefix = "Note "
)
```

Output:

```
     ID Company `Note 1`       `Note 2`          `Note 3`    
  <int> <chr>   <chr>          <chr>             <chr>       
1     1 srental skiing rentals last used 3/12/14 NA          
2     2 hertz   car rental     NA                NA          
3     3 nike    shoe orders    last used 2/14/19 www.nike.com
```

a more concise alternative, as suggested by @jpsmith:

```
pivot_wider(
  mutate(data, i=paste("Note",row_number()), .by=Company),
  names_from=i,
  values_from=Note,
)
```

Comment: Great solution! For the most recent version of `dplyr`, could reduce to `data %>% mutate(i = row_number(), .by = Company)`

Comment: thanks @jpsmith, I need to keep up!!! :)